# Deriving the Particular Solution to a Linear Discrete Dynamical System

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

In my lecture notes it says that for a linear dynamical system of the form $ f(x) = Ax $ where A is diagonalisable d x d matrix, with 
$ \left \{ v_1 , v_2, \cdots , v_d \right \} $ a basis for $ \mathbb{R^d} $ consisting of eigenvalues of A, then "it is easy to see that" $ \lambda_j^n v_j $ is a particular solution for every $ 1 \leq j \leq d $ . Thus the general solution is $ x_n = \sum_{j=1}^d c_j \lambda_j^n v_j $.

I'm finding it difficult to follow this intuition. I understand that we have $ x_{n+1} = Ax_n = A^2 x_{n-1} = \cdots = A^{n+1}x_0 $ and if A is diagonalisable with $ A = C \Lambda C^{-1} $ then this becomes $ x_n = C\Lambda^n C^{-1}x_0$ with $ \lambda_j^n $ the diagonal values of $ \Lambda^n $, however I don't see how $\lambda_j^n v_j $ is a particular solution.

What is the reasoning here?

Comment: Should say "a basis for $\mathbb{R}^d$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$...". Also, you have not said what the letter $n$ is supposed to represent. That is a problem.

Comment: n is an arbitrary 'generation' of the recurrence relation. i.e. $ x_{n+1} = f(x_n) = Ax_n  \  n = 0,1,2, \cdots $.